# How to use parameter in XQuery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I'm trying to loop the XML value using @count variable, but I'm not able to understand how to use the parameter

```
create function sbill(@s xml) 
returns varchar(max)
as begin

DECLARE @SBILLNO VARCHAR(MAX),@count int
set @count =5
while @count <> 0
Begin
   select @SBILLNO= @s.value('(/Transaction/BodyData/TransBody/BillwiseData/BillAdjustment/sBillNo)[@count]','varchar(max)')
   set @count=@count-1
end
returns @SBILLNO
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sql:variable` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable?view=sql-server-2017

Demo

```
declare @x xml =
'<a>
  <b>123</b>
  <b>456</b>
</a>'
declare @count int = 2;

select t.n.value('(/a/b)[sql:variable("@count")][1]','int')
from @x.nodes('.') t(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your own code looks, as if you want to **get multiple repeated elements** out of an XML. Therefore you are using a WHILE loop in order to read the first, the second, the nth value one after the other. Correct so far?

Assumably you are looking for this actually:

```sql
--create a mockup-table with two rows
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('<a>
      <b>b11</b>
      <b>b12</b>
      <b>b13</b>
      <b>b14</b>
      <b>b15</b>
   </a>>')
,('<a>
      <b>b21</b>
      <b>b22</b>
      <b>b23</b>
    </a>');
```

--The query

```
SELECT b.value('text()[1]','varchar(10)')
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY t.SomeXml.nodes('/a/b') A(b);
```

The `.nodes()` method will return each `<b>` in a single row as *derived table* (the table's name is `A`, the column's name is `b`. You can set both names as you like it. The returned column is of type XML and it is a **relative** fragment. The `.value()` method is used on this column to retrieve the content.

### Some hints how to avoid loops

Anyway you should avoid loops whenever you can avoid them. Your own approach could be solved in a **set-based** manner with a *tally-on-the-fly*:

```
DECLARE @count INT=5;

WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS (SELECT TOP(@count) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values)
SELECT t.ID
      ,Nmbr
      ,t.SomeXml.value('(/a/b[sql:column("Nmbr")])[1]','varchar(10)') AS Numbered_B
FROM @tbl t
CROSS JOIN Tally;
```

This will use a list of 1 to 5 in order to read the XML elements by their position using `sql:column()`. The second row will return two NULL-values, as there is no forth or fifth element.

### We could even use a dynamically created numbers list

But you can even create the *tally-on-the-fly* depending on the actual count of `<b>` elements like here:

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,Nmbr
      ,t.SomeXml.value('(/a/b[sql:column("Nmbr")])[1]','varchar(10)') AS Numbered_B
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(t.SomeXml.value('count(/a/b)','int')) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values) A(Nmbr);
```

This works like the query before, but will use a list of 1 to n, where n is found dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Few methods:
1. Use `sql:variable()`:

```
select @SBILLNO= 
@s.value('(/Transaction/BodyData/TransBody/BillwiseData/BillAdjustment/sBillNo)[sql:variable("@count")]','varchar(max)')
```

2. For more complicated queries you may need to build dynamic XQuery using dynamic SQL.